# Symfony set hidden value after submit

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a form with 2 input fields email and password(hidden) . I'm trying to generate a random value as below but failed to bind password(hidden) value after submit.

```
$password = substr(md5(rand(100000, 999999)), 0, 6);

$this->form->bind($request->setParameter('password',$password));
```

Form has the setNameformat with:

`$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('user[%s]');`

Comment: Hmmm, you could try setting a default value: $this->setDefault('password', $password);

Sorry I can't offer a solution to your described problem... I've only accomplished filling hidden forms by using default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a doctrine (or propel) form, I would do this by setting the values on the object before passing to the form constructor, and completely removing the widget from the form.

eg:

```
$o = new DoctrineOrPropelObject;
$o->setPassword($myrandomstring);
$f = new DoctrineOrPropelObjectForm($o);
```

Then display/save the form as usual - the password value will be passed right through the form process to the database when saved.

Answer (score 1):

if you use this:

```
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('user[%s]');
```

then your form input fields can be retrieved in single variable:

```
$request->getParameter('user');
```

and the value that you want to assign need to be set with something like:

```
$request->setParameter('user[password]', $password);
```

Reference can be found [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms).

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the save method of your form and add `$this->values[$field] = $value;`

Something like this:

```
public function save($con = null) 
{
        $this->values['owner_id'] = $this->values['owners_ids'][2];` 
        return parent::save($con); 
}
```